# Do Calabi -Yau shapes also influence a strings particle identity?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, elementary-particles, compactification, calabi-yau

Since strings reside on the surface of a d-brane, and it' a three dimensional hyperspace, are their manifestations as certain particles also influenced by Calabi Yau Spaces? Could the way strings resonate, and also interact with the geometry of the higher Calabi Yau special shapes, also determine their particle identity? I've read that the way strings wrap through holes in Calabi Yau shapes also has a roll in their particle appearances.

Answer (score 1):

String theory postulates  that of the elementary particles we currently know about, each relates directly to low-energy string vibrations, the presence of multiple holes causes the string patterns to fall into  families. Each hole in the Calabi-Yau space is a group of low-energy string vibrational patterns. If the C-Y has three holes, then three families of vibrational patterns and thus three families of particles will be observed experimentally.

Compare this to the [Standard Model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

[image]

Strings are thought to vibrate through all dimensions,with the shape of the compactified dimensions affecting their vibrations modes and by extension the properties of the elementary particles observed.

> For example, Andrew Strominger and Edward Witten have shown that the masses of particles depend on the manner of the intersection of the various holes in a Calabi-Yau. In other words, the positions of the holes relative to one another and to the substance of the Calabi-Yau space was found by Strominger and Witten to affect the masses of particles in a certain way. This, of course, is true of all particle properties.[3]